# Field Sets with Custom Labels

Tags: visualforce

I have a scenario wherein there are three FieldSets for an object. I want make this fieldset `{!$ObjectType.Room.fieldsets.Qualification}` in VF page dynamically. The field set name should be retrieved from Custom Label value.

I want to make '**Qualification**' dynamically get from Custom Label value, where my admin will set the field set value.

Any help pls?

Answer (score 2):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets[$Setup.AccountFieldSetSettings__c.FieldSetName__c]}" var="f">
    <apex:outputText value="{!Account[f]}" /><br/>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

In this example we are taking the fieldset name from a custom setting. If you can use a custom setting instead of a custom label, you can use the above code.
If you still want to use the custom label then you would have to replace

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets[$Setup.AccountFieldSetSettings__c.FieldSetName__c]}" var="f">
```

with

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets[$Label.Sample]}" var="f">
```

where Sample is name of the custom Label

Note : I have not tried this out myself, but i think it should work

Btw: I have shamelessly copied the code from http://foobarforce.com/2013/12/10/dynamic-field-sets/